# Unity 3d cross section shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, shader, unity3d-2dtools, 2.5d

Im trying to make a game where you scroll your 2d plane through a 3d world to solve different puzzles, but i cant seem to get a good 2d effect like in [this video](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+passing+through+2d&rlz=1C1UEAD_enUS1023US1023&biw=1920&bih=963&tbm=vid&sxsrf=AB5stBg1lMxSamy2CKoGBaDZADl0yNlf9w%3A1690300056554&ei=mO6_ZMupIaOZptQPleg8&ved=0ahUKEwjL1byzmqqAAxWjjIkEHRU0DwA4ChDh1QMIDQ&uact=5&oq=3d+passing+through+2d&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LXZpZGVvIhUzZCBwYXNzaW5nIHRocm91Z2ggMmQyBRAhGKABMgUQIRirAjIFECEYqwIyCBAhGBYYHhgdMgoQIRgWGB4YDxgdMggQIRgWGB4YHTIIECEYFhgeGB0yCBAhGBYYHhgdMggQIRgWGB4YHTIIECEYFhgeGB1I_hpQAFjeGXAAeACQAQCYAdEBoAGEHqoBBjAuMTcuM7gBA8gBAPgBAcICCBAAGIoFGJECwgIFEAAYgATCAggQABiABBixA8ICCxAAGIAEGLEDGIMBwgILEAAYigUYsQMYgwHCAgcQABiKBRhDwgINEAAYgAQYFBiHAhixA8ICChAAGIoFGLEDGEPCAgYQABgWGB7CAgcQABgNGIAEwgIGEAAYHhgNwgIIEAAYBRgeGA3CAggQABgIGB4YDcICDBAAGAUYHhgNGA8YCsICCBAAGIoFGIYDiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-video#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:9f107ad4,vid:BXngATAQ0m0) they all just seem 3d but i want just a slice of the objects going through.

I tried clipping planes and that kinda worked but not really i tried making the camera super closw which did not work at all and a bunch more. Im wondering if theres some sort of shader i could make to basically project whatever passes through the plane on the plane, but nothing in front of the plane shows. just like the video above